# VBA Code to Copy Non Blank Cells From one Sheet to Another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a VBA code to copy "Non-Blank" cells from one file to another. This code selects the last Non Blank row, but for the column it's copying `A4 to AU`. I'd like to copy columns `A4 to LastcolumnNotblank` and also last row. So basically copy `A4 to (LastColumn)(LastRow)Not Blank`

Would be really grateful if someone can help by editing the below code. Many thanks.

```
Sub Export_Template()

'' TPD

File_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Engineering TPD", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

If File_name <> False Then

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 4 To LastRow
 If Left(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value, 1) <> "" Then lastactiverow = i
 Next i
   'MsgBox (lastactiverow)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A4:AU" & lastactiverow).Select
    Selection.Copy

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=File_name, FileFormat:=51

    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: lmk if the below solution works on your end

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm assuming that `Col A` is a good indicator of where to find your last used row
2. Also assuming that `Row 1` is a good indicator of where to find your last used column
3. You need to change `Sheet1` on 3rd line of code to the name of your sheet that has the data to be copied
4. You need to declare variables (Use `Option Explicit`)
5. Avoid `.Select` and `.Selection` at all costs (none are found in below solution)
6. You did not re-enable `ScreenUpdating` and `DisplayAlerts`
7. This is tested and works **A-OK**

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Export_Template()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long
Dim FileName

FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Engineering TPD", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

If FileName <> False Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
            LRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            LCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            ws.Range(ws.Cells(4, 1), ws.Cells(LRow, LCol)).Copy
            NewBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        NewBook.SaveAs FileName:=FileName, FileFormat:=51
        NewBook.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @urdearboy, I copy pasted your code but it didn't work I got an error "Range of Object Failed" and it's highlighting yellow on the "ws.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(LRow, LCol)).Copy" I also noticed that "Option Explicit" maybe not in the right place? and yes all your assumptions are correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you change the sheet name as mentioned in #3. Option explicit is in the correct place

Comment: I found the error. Didn’t qualify a cell object. Try again - should work

Answer (score 0):

The code below will preserve your `ActiveSheet` range and use `SaveAs` to save to a new workbook with your specific name, without all the extra crap. It deletes all the sheets except for the `ActivSheet`, and deletes the first three rows, then using `SaveAs` to save to `ThisWorkbook.Path`. Your macro enabled workbook will not be changed. 
I actually don't like to use `ActiveSheet` due to the obvious problems, but since you were using it i kept it. I would suggest you use the name of the worksheet.

```
Sub SaveActiveSheetRangeAsNewWorkbook()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each ws In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
                ws.Delete
            End If
        Next

        .Sheets(1).Range("A1:A3").EntireRow.Delete
        .SaveAs Filename:="Engineering TPD", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```